# pg_restore warning column X has type unknown

Tags: postgresql, restore, datatypes, dump

I'm doing a dump from PostgreSQL 9.1 and restoring on PostgreSQL 9.4 and getting this warning

```
pg_restore: WARNING:  column "foobar" has type "unknown"
DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
```

But after the restore I can verify the column "foobar" type is defined and correct.

What could be causing this warning?

Comment: Could you give us a \d table_name?

Comment: the field name I changed to foobar but why would you need the table name?

Comment: Because it'll tell me if your SQL column names correspond to the actual table names.

Comment: Vérace wasn't not asking for the table name but for the *table definition*, which you get with `\d table_name` in psql. Add the corresponding script from your dump file to make the question complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CREATE VIEW` or `CREATE TABLE... AS SELECT` have to infer the column types for the relation to create. Sometimes the context is not sufficient to guess a datatype, for example when it's just a string literal. In this case it's created as `unknown`.

Example :

```
test=> CREATE VIEW testview AS SELECT  'bla' AS foobar;
WARNING:  column "foobar" has type "unknown"
DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
CREATE VIEW
```

Result:

```
test=> \d testview
    View "public.testview"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 foobar | unknown |
```

If this view was pg_dumped and pg_restored, the column would be created as `unknown` with again the warning mentioned:

> pg_restore: WARNING:  column "foobar" has type "unknown"
>   DETAIL: Proceeding with relation creation anyway.

The table/view should be created to begin with with explicit casts to columns when needed, as in

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS SELECT  'bla'::text AS foobar;
```

which we can assume is the point of that warning in the first place.